# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. VSC, "extension: live server"

Tags: javascript, html, host, portal

sorry, I speak spanish, I have a problem with google and other browsers, when I search for something in my two computers, cellphones(don´t load web) the console give me that bug: crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. (I can use instagram youtube and some the problem is google and some web sites)
I was learning to program using "live server" a extension in Visual studio code, and then, when I open the html proyect whit this extension (only Js file was bound to html) that give me the "host", something like : "http://localhost:4200", automaticly this open on brave so i copy it and paste it at the url on google and I work on it for a few minutes, then something about "Print" the page appears every time I save (ctrl + s) at VSCode, after all that I cant search in google and that bug appears practicly always.

bugs:
principal:
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
Other, this appear before:
[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2

I was working on those files:
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Historia de Cofla - 1</title>
        <script src="JS.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Historia de cofla</h1>
        <p>xd</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
//datos de precios de healdos:

var palitoAgua = 0.6;
var palitoCrema = 1;
var bombonHeladix = 1.6;
var bombonHeladovich = 1.7;
var bombonHelardo = 1.8;
var potecitohelado = 2.9;
var pote14 = 2.9;

//usuario

var usuario;
usuario = prompt("Dinos cuanto dinero tienes y te diremos cual helado puedes comprar!");
comparacionH(usuario);

function comparacionH(usuario){
    if (usuario >= potecitohelado){
        alert("puedes comprar todos!! puedes elegir entre 'potecito con confites a $2.9' o 'pote de 1/4 a $2.9', Te sobrarian: $" + (parseInt(usuario) - potecitohelado));
    }
    else if (usuario >= bombonHelardo){;
        alert("puedes comprar un 'Bombon Helardo' a $" + bombonHelardo + " Te sobrarian: " (usuario - bombonHelardo));
    }
    else if (usuario >= bombonHeladovich){
        alert("puedes comprar un 'Bombon Heladovich' a $" +bombonHeladovich);
    }
    else if (usuario >= bombonHeladix){
        alert("puedes comprar un 'Bombon Heladix' a $" +bombonHeladix);
    }
    else if (usuario >= palitoCrema){
        alert("puedes comprar un 'Palito de crema' a $" + palitoCrema);
    }
    else if (usuario >= palitoAgua){
        alert("puedes comprar un 'Palito de Agua' a $" + palitoAgua);
    }
    else if (usuario < palitoAgua){
        print("No te alcanza para ningun helado :c");
    }
    else {
        print("que pusiste? jsjsjs");
    }
}
```

The problem is in somewhere at "host", a "non-JS file" or at a "portal".
Hopefully you can help me, thanks! c: